# Unable to get metrics relabeling working on Grafana Agent Integrations

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, integration

I'm running Grafana Agent v0.36.2 in Static mode as a K8s operator, and I've implemented a combination of Integrations custom resources, and additionalScrapeMetrics (on the MetricsInstance custom resource).

I've receiving data from both the scraped metrics as well as the Integrations, and relabeling works perfectly on the additionalScrapedMetrics definition.

The problem is that the `metrics_relabel_configs` on ANY of my Integrations doesn't seem to do anything. I can see that the config makes it into the agent config, which means that both the controller and config-reloader are working as expected, but no relabeling takes place.

I'm sure I'm missing something terribly simple here, and would appreciate any insights.

Snipped config:

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.grafana.com/v1alpha1
kind: Integration
metadata:
  name: integration-rds-postgres-[REDACTED]
  namespace: monitoring-system
  labels:
    agent: grafana-agent
spec:
  name: cloudwatch
  type:
    allNodes: false
    unique: true
  config:
    autoscrape:
      enable: true
      metrics_instance: monitoring-system/[REDACTED]-metrics
      metrics_relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [tag_AppId,dimension_DBInstanceIdentifier]
          action: replace
          regex: (.*);.*-(.*)$
          target_label: "clusterid"
          replacement: $1-$2
        - action: labeldrop
          regex: tag_AppId|dimension_DBInstanceIdentifier|region|account
```